# Radio Button Validation in Javascript inside an iterator

Tags: javascript, jsp, radio-button

I am having radio buttons inside an iterator in jsp.

I want to check whether any of the radio button inside the list is checked in the script.

Comment: can you make it clear that you want to do it in JAvascript or JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways.

For example you can have a boolean variable in your script and a function which turns it to true. Add this function with onclick attribute to your radiobutton.
Later if you need to check whether any of populated radiobuttons was chosen, you just check if your boolean is true.

Or simply use JQuery possibilities:

Here's a function that will return true if at least one radio button is selected anywhere on the page.

```javascript
function atLeastOneRadio() {
    return ($$('input[type=radio]:checked').size() > 0);
}
```

You can check in the same way by your radiobuttons' name:

```
$('input[name=your_radiobuttons_common_name]:checked').length > 0)
```